# Difference between GET/POST/PUT/DELETE in Ajax in MVC pattern

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I understand that GET is typically associated with a URL where you can put in the browser and get the exact action done again, like viewing a profile for a particular person.

I am implementing MVC pattern with CI, and with a $.ajax of type:GET to the following URL:

```
                url         : 'index.php/con/fx1',
```

where con is the controller,
fx 1 is a function in the controller.

I can direct fx1 to any model and do anything, be it POST, DELETE, or just READ.

In this sense, what difference does it make whether I specify GET/POST/DELETE/PUT

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a ruby on rails developer. But the MVC pattern is common for all (including php framework). I'm described in my way.

```
GET    /con        #=> index  
GET    /con/1      #=> show  
GET    /con/new    #=> new  
GET    /con/1/edit #=> edit  
PUT    /con/1      #=> update  
POST   /con        #=> create  
DELETE /con/1      #=> destroy
```

for more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

Comment: for New: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472393/rails-new-vs-create
edit: The requests (show|delete, create) are transmitted by default with the right HTTP verb (here,GET and POST).

Comment: @William Sham, Please vote-up to my answer, if you are satisfied. :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in describing intent. I could, of course, submit a form using either GET or POST. The difference is that in REST a GET means one thing, a POST means another.

Even when there aren't *technical* reason for differentiating request types, there may be *conceptual* reasons for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

`GET` and `POST` serve very different purposes. As do `PUT` and `DELETE`. Rather than repeat what many, many others have already said on this topic, Google `difference between GET and POST`.