# Rails controller create action difference between Model.new and Model.create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm going through a few Rails 3 and 4 tutorial and come across something I would love some insights on:

What is the difference between the Model.new and Model.create in regards to the Create action. I thought you do use the `create` method in the controller for saving eg. `@post = Post.create(params[:post])` but it looks like I'm mistaken. Any insight is much appreciated.

## Create action using Post.new

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.save

  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

## Create action using Post.create

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.create(post_params)
  @post.save

  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

I have two questions

- Is this to do with a Rails 4 change?
- Is it bad practice to use `@post = Post.create(post_params)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails new vs create](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472393/rails-new-vs-create)

Comment: Thanks for the reference Amadan. Is Rails REST implement of `GET` and `POST` the same as the controller actions `new` and `create`? I'm trying to clarify REST vs controller actions vs controller methods.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified; the answer by Justin Ethier specifically refers to ActiveRecord methods.

Answer (score 24):

**Model.new**

The following instantiate and initialize a Post model given the params:

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
```

You have to run `save` in order to persist your instance in the database:

```
@post.save
```

**Model.create**

The following instantiate, initialize **and save** in the database a Post model given the params:

```
@post = Post.create(post_params)
```

You don't need to run the `save` command, it is built in already.

More informations on `new` [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class)

More informations on `create` [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class/)

Answer (score 0):

The `Model.new` method creates a nil model instance and the `Model.create` method additionally tries to save it to the database directly.

`Model.create` method creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.

`object = Model.create` does not need any `object.save` method to save the values in database.

---

In `Model.new` method, new objects can be instantiated as either empty (pass no construction parameter)

In `Model.new(params[:params])` pre-set with attributes but not yet saved in DB(pass a hash with key names matching the associated table column names).

After `object = Model.new`, we need to save the object by `object.save`