# Misunderstanding routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

So I set up my routes like so:

```
StartPoint::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => 'login'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => 'signup'

  resource :home, controller: 'home'
  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  root 'home#show'
end
```

How ever when ever I go to sign up and fail to fill in proper data It always takes me to `bla.com/users` instead of signup. It should always go back to sign up. my controller looks like this, for new and create

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_signup_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Some one told me that when  it fails, order to see all the error messages I need to go back to to the new method, which then displays me all my errors. How ever the new method has a completely different url structure then the create. Regardless, if there are errors - I need it to go back to `bla.com/signup`, not `bla.com/users`

Comment: In Rails, because the controllers are based on a RESTful architecture, you need to have two different routes for `new` and `create`. You want to do both with the same route. Perhaps this question might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472393/rails-new-vs-create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you have a post

```
post 'login' => 'sessions#create', :as => 'login'
get 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => 'login'
get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
get 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => 'signup'
```

Comment: throws an error stating that it has no templates for this type of set up.

Comment: just to make sure I meant in addition. get 'login brings you to the login form, post 'login' is what the form posts to.

Answer (score -1):

The action of your form is `/users`. So, after POSTing to `/users` you either need to redirect to a different url (`/signup`), or just be satisfied with the `/users` endpoint. Note: if you `redirect_to signup_path` you will lose the data you POSTed.

Your best option might be to not use a resource for your signup.

`match 'signup' => 'users#signup'`

Then in your controller, handle both POSTs and GETs:

```
def signup
  if request.post?
    @user = User.new(user_signup_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
  render :new
end
```

Documentation for the [request object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object).

Comment: Um, you never defined the method post? its not like it, it doesn't understand what it is, in fact: `NoMethodError`

Comment: My mistake, I meant `request.post?` For some reason, I thought it was directly available in controllers.